# GGplot2 - problems with aes( fill)

Tags: r, ggplot2, fill, geom-tile

I am trying to create a plot for upcoming football fixtures, with the colours based on the team's position (Pos) in the table.  However, the fill doesn't seem to be choosing the right colour for the individual tiles as shown below. I have included my data below. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
    df %>%
ggplot() +
      geom_tile(aes(x=GW,y=team,fill=Pos), colour="black") +
      geom_text(aes(x=GW,y=team,label=oppo),size=3) +
      theme_void() +
      theme(axis.text = element_text(face = "bold")) +
      theme(axis.text.y = element_text(margin=margin(0,-20,0,0))) + 
      scale_x_continuous(position="top",breaks=1:15) +
      labs(caption=paste("xxx rocks | ",Sys.Date(),sep=""))
```

[image: Plot]

Data (dput(df)):

```
structure(list(team = c("CHE", "EVE", "LEE", "NEW", "LEI", "SOU", "ARS", "WOL", "MUN", "AVL", "CHE", "CRY", "EVE", "LEE", "LEI", "MCI", "NEW", "SHU", "TOT", "WBA", "CRY", "BHA", "MCI", "BUR", "WHU", "WBA", "SHU", "FUL", "TOT", "LIV", "SOU", "BHA", "LIV", "WOL", "AVL", "ARS", "MUN", "FUL", "WHU", "BUR"), fdr = c(1070L, 1070L, 1350L, 1150L, 1100L, 1030L, 1220L, 1030L, 1260L, 1350L, 1060L, 1070L, 1350L, 1190L, 1080L, 1270L, 1250L, 1030L, 1100L, 1150L, 1200L, 1100L, 1030L, 1090L, 1180L, 1150L, 1190L, 1200L, 
1250L, 1050L, 1200L, 1080L, 1100L, 1030L, 1180L, 1310L, 1090L, 1170L, 1200L, 1020L), Pos = c(9, 3, 7, 10, 1, 15, 5, 16, 14, 4, 9, 6, 3, 7, 1, 13, 10, 19, 8, 17, 6, 12, 13, 18, 11, 17, 19, 20, 8, 2, 15, 12, 2, 16, 4, 5, 14, 20, 11, 18), GW = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), home = c("CHE", "EVE", "LEE", "NEW", "LEI", "SOU", "ARS", "WOL", "MUN", "AVL", "CHE", "CRY", "EVE", "LEE", "LEI", "MCI", "NEW", "SHU", "TOT", "WBA", "CHE", "EVE", "LEE", "NEW", "LEI", "SOU", "ARS", "WOL", "MUN", "AVL", "CHE", 
"CRY", "EVE", "LEE", "LEI", "MCI", "NEW", "SHU", "TOT", "WBA"), away = c("CRY", "BHA", "MCI", "BUR", "WHU", "WBA", "SHU", "FUL", "TOT", "LIV", "SOU", "BHA", "LIV", "WOL", "AVL", "ARS", "MUN", "FUL", "WHU", "BUR", "CRY", "BHA", "MCI", "BUR", "WHU", "WBA", "SHU", "FUL", "TOT", "LIV", "SOU", "BHA", "LIV", "WOL", 
"AVL", "ARS", "MUN", "FUL", "WHU", "BUR"), oppo = structure(c(6L, 3L, 12L, 4L, 19L, 18L, 15L, 8L, 17L, 11L, 16L, 3L, 11L, 20L, 2L, 1L, 13L, 8L, 19L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 9L, 14L, 10L, 16L, 1L, 20L, 13L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 10L, 12L, 14L, 15L, 17L, 18L), .Label = c("ARS", "AVL", "BHA", "BUR", "CHE", "CRY", "EVE", "FUL", "LEE", "LEI", "LIV", "MCI", "MUN", "NEW", "SHU", "SOU", "TOT", "WBA", "WHU", "WOL"), class = "factor"), G_A = c(6, 3, 7, 4, 4, 6, 4, 7, 5, 0, 6, 3, 3, 7, 4, 6, 4, 4, 4, 11, 3, 6, 6, 5, 4, 11, 4, 10, 4, 
4, 6, 6, 4, 7, 0, 4, 5, 10, 4, 5), G_F = c(6, 8, 8, 3, 12, 3, 6, 3, 4, 4, 6, 5, 8, 8, 12, 5, 3, 0, 6, 5, 5, 6, 5, 2, 5, 5, 0, 3, 6, 9, 3, 6, 9, 3, 4, 6, 4, 3, 5, 2), PTS = c(4, 9, 6, 4, 9, 3, 6, 3, 3, 6, 4, 6, 9, 6, 9, 3, 4, 0, 4, 1, 6, 3, 3, 0, 3, 1, 0, 0, 4, 9, 3, 3, 9, 3, 6, 6, 3, 0, 3, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
-40L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Unfortunately this hasn't worked, although rows are different colours the individual cells don't code how they should. It has highlighted though that the cells seems to be colouring from the team in left hand label, rather than the team in the cell.

Comment: Perhaps this means i need to change my data

Comment: @BulletTooth yes, but just a single line of code as shown in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you perhaps trying to make the fill color according to the *opponents'* position? If so, you will need to calculate this for each row before plotting using `match`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(oppo_pos = Pos[match(oppo, team)]) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_tile(aes(x = GW, y = team, fill = oppo_pos), colour = "black") +
  geom_text(aes(x = GW, y = team, label = oppo), size = 3) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(face = "bold")) +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(margin=margin(0, -20, 0, 0))) + 
  scale_x_continuous(position = "top",breaks = 1:15) +
  labs(caption = paste("xxx rocks | ", Sys.Date(), sep = "")) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = c("forestgreen", "gold", "tomato"))
```

[image]